# How to pass an image to data attributes in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am integrating a template into Rails. Every thing has been set up but I have a problem in slider.
This portion of slider is causing problems. I am passing images from assets to data attributes 1: data-thumb & 2: data-lazyload but it says Error 404 resource not found.

Static Template HTML

```
<li data-transition="zoomout" data-slotamount="7" data-easein="default" data-easeout="default" data-masterspeed="300" data-thumb="images/slider/bg4.jpg" data-rotate="0" data-saveperformance="off" data-title="Slide" data-description="on">
<!-- MAIN IMAGE -->
<img src="images/dummy.png" alt="laptopmockup_sliderdy" data-lazyload="images/slider/bg1.jpg">
```

Rails Template

```
<li data-transition="zoomout" data-slotamount="7" data-       easein="default" data-easeout="default" data-masterspeed="300" data: {thumb: image_path("bg5.jpg")} data-rotate="0" data-saveperformance="off" data-title="Slide" data-description="on">
<!-- MAIN IMAGE -->
<%= image_tag("dummy.png", alt:"laptopmockup_sliderdy", data: {    lazyload: 'slider/bg1.jpg'}) %>
```

I have tried these methods

```
data-thumb="<%= image_tag('slider/bg4.jpg")
data-thumb="<%= image_path('slider/bg4.jpg")
data-thumb="<%= asset_path('slider/bg4.jpg")
```

&

```
data: {lazyload: 'slider/bg1.jpg'}
```

but none of this work.Kindly guide me to make this correct.

Comment: What kind of slider are you using? And what exactly do you want to pass to the data attribute? Is it suppose to be an URL to the image?

Comment: I want to pass image from the asset pipeline... and I am using revolution slider

Comment: So URL of the image? `image_tag` method should return the URL. Where is the image located? Your code is looking for image located in `/app/assets/images/slider` directory. Also what does it mean "none of this work"? Is there any error?

Comment: I have updated the question @MarekTakac

Comment: And what about the data-lazyload="img path"

Comment: This is main part if this works than every thing will be alright